# Displaying add to cart button upon mouse-over?

Tags: e-commerce, placement

I noticed that on Etsy, when you mouse over products after conducting a search, two buttons display in the upper right hand corner to either "heart" the product or add the product to a list. How effective would that kind of interaction be with an add to cart button?

Comment: This is one of many cases where you need to fail gracefully.  Apart from touchscreen-only devices loading the desktop version of the site, some "appear-on-mouseover" features are implemented badly enough to be hard to catch (e.g. the straight line from the mouseover item to the item you want to click triggers something else -- quite common on mouseover menus)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a retail site, I would consider "Add To Cart" to be a piece of core functionality.  Implementation of core functionality should not magically appear and disappear.  While it seems relatively clear in your description, I think this can be confusing to users.  If they have not hovered over an item yet, there will not have been an "Add to Cart" button/link available to them at all.

Comment: That is a fair point. However, you will also note on the Etsy site that there is no add to cart button to be found at all on their page.

Comment: I never said I liked their site design ;)  However, I have purchased from them, so I guess it didn't turn me off too much.

Comment: Agreed, in addition, remember that mobile devices don't have hover states!

Comment: Definitely.  I am annoyed to no end by websites that implement menus based on hover.  Worthless on my phone

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to put the category name above the filters and orders button. In this way is more clear that all content below the category belongs to the selected category (proximity). In addition in this way you can put a label in the order dropdown to make it more clear.